# Mechanical/electronic chalkboard cleaning device to replace the conventional duster to clean the chalkboard

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, design, product-engineering

The chalk board duster which is used by teachers to wipe the chalkboard seems very agonizing for them. What new mechanical/electronic devices can be devised to replace conventional chalkboard duster which can be easily operated by teachers. Please suggest product design approach for such new cleaning device. Thanks
**ps:  I am not allowed to replace chalkboard to whiteboard**
[image: chalkboard]

Comment: Get a student to do it.

Comment: It is called a chalkboard... pc police anywhere? Especially as the one in the image is green.

Comment: Overhead projector with rolls of transparency so no need to erase lecture notes was the go to for my professors. Added benefit was the room needed to be darker so it was easier to fall asleep.

Comment: You can look for design mechanism which can reduce work of teacher to move and wiping over large areas. I don't see possibility of any product which would be cheaper than conventional duster.

Comment: @SolarMike Blackboard and Chalkboard are synonyms.  Basically the same thing.  I heard both terms used while going through school regardless of the colour of the actual board.

Comment: @Transistor - but choose them with care. I diluted the wash water with nitrogen tri-iodide I cooked up in chemistry class. When the teacher tried to write on the board, the chalk just frittered away, leaving a pretty swirl of purple iodine smoke as they went :) *Voila* reactive armor chalk board never needs cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

There are already comercial products like this. They exist primarily in the asian market. They usually consist of a vertical machine which moves along a rail at the top and bottom of the board. There are two common approaches:

1. [Water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VB3FGRPSqsI)
2. [Vacuum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xwCwbKrZQc)

The water approach is what most would be familliar with. It has been used for ages with the usual handheld sponge. What you need here is basicly a big vertical sponge (or multiple small ones) and a way to provide water. This can be done easily by use of a hose and/or letting the water drip through the sponge. Behind the sponge unit should be a way to remove the water like a [squeegee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeegee). You can either make the robot only work in one direction or you need to have two squeegee with only one deployed at a time.

The vacuum method is less common and louder but doesn't need any water to function. It is not just like sucking air from the board. Instead there will be a moving belt to collect the chalk and a vacuum to remove it from the belt. There are also [handheld versions of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MAa2_e6Z8Q). Keep in mind that this dry method can create the problem of dust to be contained. So this will certainly be harder.

In conclusion I belive the Water method would be easiest for a prototype. However in real classrooms the problem of stagnant water can quickly become a problem. A drying function could help here.

I would also reccomend reading [this paper](http://ijlret.com/Papers/Vol-2-issue-12/4-B2016445.pdf) which seems to be very similar to you task.

Comment: Thanks for answer, if you may provide some information about the material used for wiping action, it will be helpful for me. Thanks again, I am awarding you the bounty for your answer.

Comment: For cleaning the chalk i would simply use multiple conventional sponges put together. for water delivery I would put a hose with some holes along the sponges backside. If you want to use a squeegee you might find something usefull at an autopart store (like windscreen wipers). Keep in mind that while a squeegee gives you the benefit of a less wet board it will certainly create friction to be dealt with.